# Call him "John" - after

Tags: idioms

in this phrase (They are going to call him John - after John, his grandfather). what is meant by (after John,)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence uses 'after' as a preposition. Here 'after' means 'the boy was given the same name as his grandfather, which is John.'

See definition 11 of after (preposition) in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/after):

> 11. PREPOSITION.
>
> To be named after someone means to be given the same name as them.
>   [British].
>
> *Phillimore Island is named after Sir Robert Phillimore.
>
>   He persuaded Virginia to name the baby after him.*

Comment: I added the quoted definition instead of having a link-only reference.   Not sure I agree that “after” is just British though.  Plenty of AmE speakers use *after* in this sense.